# OpenCV - RTSP stream not opening

Tags: opencv, udp, rtsp, ip-camera

I have a RTPS streaming camera. The stream works fine when I test it with VLC:

`vlc -vvv rtsp://192.168.0.23:554/stream`

However with openCV it does not open:

`cv::VideoCapture capture;
bool ok = capture.open("rtsp://192.168.0.23:554/stream");`

returns false.

What can be the reason?

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar problem. In my case the dll starts with "opencv_ffmpeg" was missing in the run path.

Comment: Guys, this is actually a correct answer! Well maybe there are some other cases, but adding 'opencv_ffmpeg320_64.dll' (chose your version) fixed my case. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

If you are using `OpenCV 4+` you need to copy the `ffmpeg` related `dll` and paste it next to your executable. For example I've built my `OpenCV` with the `BUILD_opencv_world` option and I have a file named `opencv_videoio_ffmpeg430_64.dll` in my `bin` folder in the my `build` directory. Without that file it won't open the stream and shows nothing.

Answer (score 0):

On MacOS this solution works for me.

```
os.environ['OPENCV_FFMPEG_CAPTURE_OPTIONS'] = 'rtsp_transport;http'
```

The transport is not TCP, but HTTP

Answer (score -1):

When using the VideoCaptuer class with OpenCV 4, in C++, it does not work with RTSP streams.

Answer (score -3):

you can do it by OpenCV and python as below:

```
import cv2
str1=cv2.VideoCapture("RTSP Address")
while True:
    _,frame=str1.read()
    cv2.imshow('SOMENAME',frame)
    s=cv2.waitkey(0)
```

Comment: adding an explanation to the answer would help

Comment: explanations about which section ! ?